# Suggestions on How to execute SQL script using VBA in Oracle Database

Tags: excel, database, vba, oracle, sql-scripts

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Pick up SQL script from a worksheet(script has comments and queries)
2. Assign it to a string variable with the value of range of cells(where the scripts are pasted) from the worksheet
3. Execute the script by passing the string variable to ADODB connection I made before as a recordset
4. Paste the results of the script executed in the Oracle Database in a new sheet

So far what I have achieved:

1. Database connection was successful
2. I am able to assign the range values to a variant but not a string (Error: Type Mismatch)
3. If I change the variable to a variant then I am not able to execute it as a recordset. 
   (Error: arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another)

I know the approach I am using is not that easy therefore I need suggestions on how I may be able to achieve this.

```vb
Private Sub RunValidation_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheet As Variant
Dim StrSQL As Variant
Dim sheetnumber As Integer
Dim irow As Integer
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim elementcount As Integer

Call OptimizeCode_Begin
Call Start_DBConnect

irow = ScriptExecutor.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
elementcount = irow - 13

StrSQL = ScriptExecutor.Range("A14: A" & irow).Value


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open StrSQL, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

If Not rs.EOF Then
rs.MoveFirst
End If

i = 1
sheetnumber = Application.Sheets.count - i
Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
ws.name = "Extracts-" & sheetnumber

Sheets("Extracts-" & sheetnumber).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is the SQL script contained in column A from row 14 down, each cell is 1 line of script  so the full script is all those cells joined with CRLF ?

Comment: @CDP1802 - Yes the script is in column A and starts from row 14, but it has comments as well as queries in it. Each cell is not one line of script and some rows maybe empty. They are not joined by CRLF.  I'll add an image of the script as well.

Comment: What I meant was if all the lines were joined with carriage return/line feeds into a single string would that be the SQL you were trying to execute ?. That would be executing 3 select statement one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining each row in the range with CRLF to create a string. The array assigned from the range is a single column with many rows. The JOIN function needs a single row many columns array hence the transpose function.

```vb
   Dim StrSQL As String, arLines As Variant
   arLines = ScriptExecutor.Range("A14: A" & irow).Value
   StrSQL = Join(Application.Transpose(arLines), vbCrLf)
```

If you have to ignore the --comments including those on the same line as a statement (and the blank lines) then building the string one line at a time is probably the simplest method.

```vb
Dim cell As Range, sLine As String, StrSQL As String
With ScriptExecutor.Range("A14: A" & irow)
    For Each cell In .Cells
        sLine = Trim(cell.Value)

        ' remove any comments --
        i = InStr(1, sLine, "--", vbTextCompare)
        If i > 0 Then
             sLine = Left(sLine, i - 1)
        End If

        If len(sLine) = 0 Then
            ' skip blank lines
        Else
            If Len(StrSQL) > 0 Then sLine = vbCrLf & sLine
            StrSQL = StrSQL & sLine
        End If
    Next
End With
Debug.Print StrSQL
```

With multiple queries in the same script you get multiple record sets so try using .nextRecordSet method.

```vb
Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Extracts-" & sheetnumber

Set rs = oCon.Execute(sql)

iRow = 2
Do Until rs Is Nothing
    With ws
        .Range("A" & iRow).CopyFromRecordset rs
        iRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2
    End With
    Set rs = rs.nextRecordSet
Loop
```

Comment: @ CDP1802 - Thank you for the solution. After implementing your solution I was at least able to pass the variable into a recordset to execute but, now, when I execute these statements  'Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open StrSQL, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText', I get an error: "define not done before fetch or execute and fetch". Turns out, that I will have to remove the comments, so I was wondering if there is a way to leave the comments as it is and try to handle it in my code?

Comment: @siddhant.jain I'm surprised that Oracle doesn't ignore the comment lines, is it on Unix ?  I have updated my code anyway

Comment: @CDP1802-I implemented your solution but it doesn't seem to be working on all the queries. I wonder why. Example(sorry don't know how to add an image):                                                                                            --number of web request not in final status
select count(web_request_id) from TOLL_DBA.Web_request
where web_request_status not in ('A', 'J');

-- number of web users =
select  count (*) from TOLL_DBA.Web_user;
select count(account_id) from toll_dba.account;
select account_type, count(account_type) from toll_dba.account
group by account_type;

Comment: @siddhant.jain Have you tried running the queries separately. ? Do they work in an Oracle client like SQL Developer ? I can really only help with the VBA, I am not an Oracle DBA.

Comment: @CDP1802- Yes, If I just copy all the queries and run it in SQL Developer as a script everything works. I execute the query first in SQL Developer then paste in the worksheet so that there is no syntax error.

Comment: @siddhant.jain I have update my answer with additional info about multiple record sets

Comment: @CDP1802- thank you for your answers. I came across a slightly different approach but based on your answers. I have posted my answer below, let me know your feedback

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve the above question with a slightly different approach. The only precondition is that the user will have to remove the comments from the script.

The script looks something like this:
[Sample Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybcOt.png).

and the code is as follows:

```
Private Sub RunValidation_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheet As Variant
Dim sheetnumber As Integer
Dim irow As Integer
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.field
Dim elementcount As Integer
Dim sqlscript As Variant
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim commands As Variant
Dim cmd() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim results As String
Dim rownum As Integer
Dim col As Integer

On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err

If ScriptExecutor.TextUser = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter User ID.")
    GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Exit
End If

If ScriptExecutor.TextPwd = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter Password.")
    GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Exit
End If

Call OptimizeCode_Begin
Call Start_DBConnect

' Figuring out the last row with data
irow = ScriptExecutor.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
elementcount = irow - 13

' Assigning range to a Variant variable
sqlscript = ScriptExecutor.Range("A14: A" & irow).Value

'Converting into String
StrSQL = Join(Application.Transpose(sqlscript), vbCrLf)

' Break the script into semi-colon
commands = Split(StrSQL, ";")

' Transfer values from array with empty values to array with empty values in the end
ReDim cmd(0 To 0)
j = 0

For i = LBound(commands) To UBound(commands)
    If commands(i) <> "" Then
        j = j + 1
        cmd(UBound(cmd)) = commands(i)
        ReDim Preserve cmd(0 To UBound(cmd) + 1)
    End If
Next i

'remove that empty array field at the end
If UBound(cmd) > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve cmd(0 To UBound(cmd) - 1)
End If


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Open new sheet to paste results
k = 2
sheetnumber = Application.Sheets.count - k
Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
ws.name = "Extracts-" & sheetnumber

' Copy results in new sheet with field names
rownum = 1
For i = LBound(cmd) To UBound(cmd)
rs.Open cmd(i), cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
rs.MoveFirst
    col = 1
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
    With ws.Cells(rownum, col)
    .Value = fld.name: .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft: .VerticalAlignment = xlTop: .EntireColumn.AutoFit: .Font.Bold = True: .Borders.Color = vbBlack
    End With
    col = col + 1
    Next

    rownum = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    With ws.Range("A" & rownum)
    .CopyFromRecordset rs:
    .Borders.Color = vbBlack
    rownum = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 2
    End With

rs.Close
Next

Set rs = Nothing

UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
Call OptimizeCode_End
Call End_DBConnect

Exit Sub

UserForm_Initialize_Err:
MsgBox Err.number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"

Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit
End Sub
```

This seems to be working perfectly at the moment but I am testing it with different scenarios.

Comment: Since you are running the select statements individually, joining them into one string and then splitting on semi-colon to me seems overly complicated especially with the array building afterwards. I would simply scan down the sheet (ignoring blank and comment lines) and build a SQL statement line by line. When you encounter a line ending ; then execute that query,  ideally as a separate sub called something  like getResults(SQL) . Set the SQL back to "" and continue scanning.

Comment: @CDP1802 - Thanks, I'll look into it.